# Combine two sql queries into a single table

Tags: sql

I have two SQL queries where uses an inner join first to match based on a condition, and the other does not. Ultimately, I would like the difference between the columns created by each query. How can I do this?

I have tried unioning and joining the queries as in some similar posts, but it won't work. I wonder if the issue is around the joins within each query.

Query 1 :

```
SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id AND A.date = B.date
AND B.col1 = 'value1'
LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
WHERE A.col1 = 'value2'
AND C.category = 'cat1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Query 2 :

```
SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
WHERE A.col1 = 'value2'
AND C.category = 'cat1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Comment: Can you define what you mean by "difference"? The "difference" between 1970-Jan-01 and 1970-Jan-03 is either "2 days" or "yes"

Comment: Your queries are very similar and could mabye be optimized in a single, shorter query. It would help if you would provide sample data and expected output...

Comment: NB : in both queries, the presence of `C.category=...` in the `WHERE` clause defeats the `LEFT JOIN C` (that is, it turns it into an `INNER JOIN`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your left join of `c` is actually turned to an inner join because it's used in a `NULL` excluding expression in the `WHERE` clause. So you can directly inner join `c` and left join `b`. Then you can use a case in one `count()` to count only the instances where a row from `b` was joined. Subtract that value from another `count()` counting all occurrences to get difference.

```
SELECT a.date,
       count(DISTINCT a.id)
       -
       count(DISTINCT CASE
                        WHEN b.id IS NOT NULL THEN
                          a.id
                      END)
       FROM a
            INNER JOIN c
                       ON c.key = a.key
                          AND c.category = 'cat1'
            LEFT JOIN b
                      ON a.id = b.id
                         AND a.date = b.date
                         AND b.col1 = 'value1'
       WHERE a.col1 = 'value2'
       GROUP BY 1
       ORDER BY 1 DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)
FROM A
INNER JOIN B
ON A.id = B.id AND A.date = B.date
AND B.col1 = 'value1'
LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
WHERE A.col1 = 'value2'
AND C.category = 'cat1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC

UNION 

SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id)
FROM A
LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
WHERE A.col1 = 'value2'
AND C.category = 'cat1'
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to `JOIN` the two queries, using the `date` column, which is available in both queries :

```
SELECT x.date, x.cnt, y.cnt, y.cnt - x.cnt
FROM 
(
    SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) AS cnt
    FROM A
    INNER JOIN B ON A.id = B.id AND A.date = B.date AND B.col1 = 'value1'
    LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
    WHERE A.col1 = 'value2' AND C.category = 'cat1'
    GROUP BY 1
) AS x 
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT A.date, COUNT(DISTINCT A.id) AS cnt
    FROM A
    LEFT JOIN C on C.key = A.key
    WHERE A.col1 = 'value2' AND C.category = 'cat1'
    GROUP BY 1
) AS y ON x.date = y.date
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

You might want to adapt the join type according to your data layout :

- `LEFT JOIN` if all dates are available in the first subquery but may be missing in the second subquery
- `RIGHT JOIN` if the situation is the other way around
- `FULL OUTER JOIN` if you want all available dates from both ends

If you choose any of the above option, you would need to use `COALESCE` to prevent the substraction to return `NULL` when one of the terms is `NULL`.